# How to Run multiple VS projects under same solution one after another?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I know the option "multiple start up projects" which Runs projects "simultaneously" ,not sequentially. I need to run multiple projects one after another and have the order which I want to run in.
what is the best known way to do the job?
I see a option of creating batch file that would require every project path to written in script ?  is there any other way?

Comment: Why not set one startup project and this one does all the jobs?

Comment: Since there's no *general* concept of "run this program when the current program exits", or similar, then use whatever tool (e.g. batch file, PS script etc) that you'd use to *run them later after development has finished*.